# JavaScript Use-API vs Java Use-API

Tags: aem, sightly

Is there any known limitation/restriction on using JavaScript Use-API?

Reading adobe documentation (links below) there is no comparison between the two technologies.

Do you know something that can't be accomplished by using JavaScript Use-API that would require to use Java Use-API? Is JavaScript Use-API a subset of Java Use-API? Are they fully compatible?

Thank you.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly/use-api-in-javascript.html

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly/use-api-in-java.html

**Please notice that this is NOT a question about: "do you prefer this or that?" or "what is you personal choice?" The purpose of my question is only to know if there are known limitations of JavaScript API over Java API**

Answer (score 3):

No. there are no limitations functionality wise. whatever can be done using java use api can be done using javascript api.

A (very) brief pros and cons analysis is available [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly.html#Choosing%20The%20Appropriate%20Use%20API).

Edit: as pointed out by [vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/831507/vlad), js is compiled into java by Rhino which has some limitations as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Requirements_and_Limitations).

Comment: JavaScript is compiled to Java at runtime using Rhino. Rhino has a couple of limitations itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Requirements_and_Limitations